# Price Range Slider in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [vueSlider](https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component)

I am not sure how to implement the slider into `computed:one() function`? use the fetched data on the slider? Really appreciate any examples for this...

I gave the value in the data. But in the compute how to use fetched data for the filter.

```js
data() {
        return {
            estates: [],
            keyword: '',
            regions:[],
            sortType:'',
            rooms:[],
            slider:{value: [0, 4000],width: '100%',height: 8,dotSize: 16,min: 0, max: 5000,disabled: false,show: true,
              useKeyboard: true,
              tooltip: 'always',
              formatter: '¥{value}',
              enableCross: false,
              mergeFormatter: '¥{value1} ~ ¥{value2}'}
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('/ajax').then((response) => {
            this.estates = response.data;
        });
    },
    computed: {
        one: function () {
            let filteredStates = this.estates.filter((estate) => {
                return (this.keyword.length === 0 || estate.includes(this.keyword)) &&
                (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(estate.rooms)) &&
                (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(estate.region))});

                if(this.sortType == 'price') {
                    filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => prev.price - curr.price);
                }
                if(this.sortType == 'created_at') {
                    filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(prev.created_at) - Date.parse(curr.created_at));
                }

                return filteredStates;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <vue-slider ref="slider3" v-bind="slider" v-model="slider.value"></vue-slider>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `this.slider.value` in your computed.

Comment: could you please show me that, and need to use price column too in (estate.price) @RoyJ

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change `value: [0, 4000]` to `value: 0`. The `min` and `max` is where you set the boundaries of your slider.

And then in the computed you do:

```
filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.price <= this.slider.value});
```

The final code should look like this:

```
data() {
        return {
            estates: [],
            keyword: '',
            regions:[],
            sortType:'',
            rooms:[],
            slider:{value: 0,width: '100%',height: 8,dotSize: 16,min: 0, max: 5000,disabled: false,show: true,
              useKeyboard: true,
              tooltip: 'always',
              formatter: '¥{value}',
              enableCross: false,
              mergeFormatter: '¥{value1} ~ ¥{value2}'}
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.get('/ajax').then((response) => {
            this.estates = response.data;
        });
    },
    computed: {
        one: function () {
            let filteredStates = this.estates.filter((estate) => {
                return (this.keyword.length === 0 || estate.includes(this.keyword)) &&
                (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(estate.rooms)) &&
                (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(estate.region))});

                if(this.sortType == 'price') {
                    filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => prev.price - curr.price);
                }
                if(this.sortType == 'created_at') {
                    filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(prev.created_at) - Date.parse(curr.created_at));
                }

                filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.price <= this.slider.value});

                return filteredStates;
        }
    }
```

Try it and let me know if it works. Cheers

Comment: it's working but, i need to two handle in slider if I change value from `value: [0, 4000] `to this `value: 0.` then I have just one handle...

Comment: I have tried to use it with two handlers but it's not getting the right value on the first handler. It is probably an issue with the VueSlider component. Please let me know if you work that out